# Assignment into a variable used as an event handler is not reactive:

Tags: javascript, dom-events, svelte

In the following code (`onMount` is omitted for brevity), both the `count` and `handler` props are used in the h1 element. The `handler` variable is updated after 3 seconds; but it does not change the behaviour of the element.

What is the best way to have something like this where the handler's definition needs to change dynamically?

```
<script>
let count = 0;
let handler = () => {};

function update() {
    if (count >= 3) {handler = () => {count = 0;}}
    count++;
}
setInterval(update, 1000);
</script>

<h1 on:click={handler}>{count}</h1>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/cb0469ba5d8241e382677ad95a659b76?version=3.12.1

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug — mind [raising an issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues)?

Answer (score 1):

Wow that's a good one, I would have expected your code to work! It looks like Svelte isn't updating the `on:click` binding when there's a reactive update, which is weird!

As a work-around, you can give `on:click` an anonymous function that calls the dynamically changed function, like this:

```html
<h1 on:click={() => handler()}>{count}</h1>
```

That seems to do the trick. Here's an [updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/170a3b92734b439881aea6f08b44d4a0?version=3.12.1)

Comment: Yes, if I have another function that calls handler (in my real test, that caller function has to check if handler is undefined or not first).  That makes it work, but a bit... unsatisfactory.